# apex:slds is not working in Napili Community

Tags: visualforce, community, lightning-experience, napili, slds

apex:slds tag works in Lightning Experience where as it is not working in Napili Community.This visualforce page is added as action button.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
 <apex:slds/>
 <apex:pageBlock >
 <apex:pageblockSection columns="2">
 <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Name}"/>
 <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Type}"/>
 <apex:outputField value="{!Account.BillingStreet}"/>
 <apex:outputField value="{!Account.BillingCity}"/>
 <apex:outputField value="{!Account.BillingState}"/>
 </apex:pageblockSection>
 </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have any css rules that only apply to the lightning community? under branding for example

Comment: I didn't added any css rules under branding.

Comment: Looks like the apex tags you are using are not fully supported by SLDS as mentioned below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's true that SLDS doesn't support `apex:pageBlock`, what you do see is the global font and spacing changes provided by SLDS.

I'm guessing the iFrame used in Lightning Communities doesn't pre-scope the markup for you. Try wrapping it in a `<div class="slds-scope"> [content goes here] </div>`?

But if you're not even trying to use SLDS classes, maybe you might want to experiment with a brand-spanking-new feature to style Visualforce pages like Lightning. So you could also try removing `<apex:slds/>` and instead adding the attribute `lightningStylesheets="true"` to your `apex:pageBlock`. Make sure the Visualforce page has API version set to 41.

Comment: none of those options will work (tested) additionally, its the SLDS that doesn't fully support those tags, not really a question of enabling lightningStylesheets or using the apex:slds tag, since all they do is actually reference the SLDS.

Comment: lightningStylesheets actually does not use the SLDS sheet at all. It's a special stylesheets that skins the standard Visualforce classes with styles that fit in with Lightning.

Comment: O.o, good to know. Still, doesn't work though :/

Comment: Does seem like a strange bug though. I guess the temp workaround is to hard-code a static resource stylesheet?

Comment: Wrapping with <div class="slds-scope"> [content goes here] </div> solved this issue. Thank you @CharlesT

Answer (score 1):

From the SLDS  [Documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/visualforce/):

> Apex tags such as `<apex:pageblock>` and `<apex:inputField>` are not yet
>   supported for use with the Salesforce Lightning Design System.

So, it is normal that SLDS is not applied to your page.

However, a few remarks:

If you check your network tab, you will see that the static resource for loading the Lightning design system is never actually found - it returns a 404 when loading in the Iframe from Lightning communities (in preview mode). This part looks like a bug.

[image]

If you remove the tag, you will see that there is no attempt to load it at all.

After publishing your site and accessing it (not in preview mode), the url path of the static resource will be the correct one (Status 200). Thus you might be unable to fully test SLDS tags in VF pages within communities until you publish your site and access it.

Comment: That seems like a bug of the incorrectly constructed url variety.

Comment: for site preview and builder yes, however, once the community is published (and accessing the live site), the url seems to work, however,  the end result is the same, no styling applied - pageblock is not supported by SLDS